# Is a tenant created from Azure Active Directory completely independent?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

If I created a new tenant (of type *Azure Active Directory*, **not** *B2C*) using the Azure Active Directory as shown in the screenshot, is the tenant in any way *linked* to my existing tenant or organization? Do they share any policy or setting, or is the new tenant completely independent from the one I originally logged into with the Azure portal?

[image]

Comment: Completely independent I think. Because when you create a tenant, you need to provide a domain to represent your organization. And the most important thing I think is that one subscription could only be tied to one tenant, but one tenant could have many tenants, and subscription is a billing and resource limitation boundary. So if two tenants has intersect, how to define costs? This is my points, and I haven't found evidence to prove indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, the tenants you create in Azure Active Directory are completely independent. The [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/licensing-directory-independence) has a clear explanation:

> In Azure Active Directory (Azure AD), each Azure AD organization is
> fully independent: a peer that is logically independent from the other
> Azure AD organizations that you manage. This independence between
> organizations includes resource independence, administrative
> independence, and synchronization independence. There is no
> parent-child relationship between organizations.